# Cancel Upload for a single file stops the upload for all files - Dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, dropzone.js

> When I start uploading multiple files using the following code, **addRemoveLinks: true** gives the option to Cancel Upload. When I cancel any one of the files getting uploaded, it stops uploading all the files. It also shows total progress percentage as 100% after that.

Can anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong? I want that on cancelling the upload for a single file should not affect the upload of other files.
How can I do this?

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { 

    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    maxFilesize: 1000,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
            if(atLeastOneIsChecked)
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            else
                alert("Please select a company!");
        });

        myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
            // Update progress bar with the value in the variable "progress", which 
            // is the % total upload progress from 0 to 100
            $("#prog").html(progress);
        });

        myDropzone.on("drop", function (event) {
            // Update progress bar with the value in the variable "progress", which 
            // is the % total upload progress from 0 to 100
            $("#prog").html("0");
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by modifing the source code.

```
Dropzone.prototype.cancelUpload = function (file) {
    var groupedFile, groupedFiles, _i, _j, _len, _len1, _ref;
    if (file.status === Dropzone.UPLOADING) {
        this.emit("canceled", file);
    } else if ((_ref = file.status) === Dropzone.ADDED || _ref === Dropzone.QUEUED) {
        file.status = Dropzone.CANCELED;
        this.emit("canceled", file);
        if (this.options.uploadMultiple) {
            this.emit("canceledmultiple", [file]);
        }
    }
    if (this.options.autoProcessQueue) {
        return this.processQueue();
    }
};
```